# Mimetypes for ImageIO read() and write()

Tags: java, mime-types, javax.imageio

I am trying to use Mime Types to define the output for ImageIO. The simple write() method

```
public static boolean write(RenderedImage im,
            String formatName,
            OutputStream output)
                     throws IOException
```

uses " informal name of the format." (e.g. "png"). Is there a simple equivalent for mimetypes (e.g.  "image/png") or failing that code that achieves the purpose of writing an image? The only starting point I have found is

```
public static Iterator<ImageWriter> getImageWritersByMIMEType(String MIMEType)
```

which seems much more complex, requiring `ImageWriter`, `IIOStream` etc. and I haven't managed to create a solution.

UPDATE: The reason I am using MIME is that it is a formal part of the image in SVG, e.g.

```
 xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...
```

and it seemed appropriate to use it rather than converting it to less defined "informal" formats. I managed to find a precise solution (in java2s.com) to my question and have added it as an answer.

Comment: *"..or failing that a workaround?"*  'Workaround' for what?  You don't mention any 'bug' in that question.

Comment: sorry - I should have written "code that achieves the same purpose"

Comment: @AndrewThompson: does his recent edit give you better understanding of his problem? I'm still a bit confused as to what he's trying to do and how his current solution fails.

Comment: I don't have a current solution - I don't know exactly which classes I should be using.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  No, not really.  I'd ignore the mime types & just choose one of the file types returned by `ImageIO` - & be done with it.  I see no benefit to doing it any other way.

Comment: Thanks - I've actually now found a solution to my question and will post this as an answer. But as you suggest it may be overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have now found a formal solution to my question on a [java2s tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/WriteImagewithImageWriter.htm)

```
public class Main {
  static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    int width = 200, height = 200;
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D ig2 = bi.createGraphics();
    ig2.fillRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);

    Iterator imageWriters = getImageWritersByMIMEType("image/gif");
    ImageWriter imageWriter = (ImageWriter) imageWriters.next();
    File file = new File("filename.gif");
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(file);
    imageWriter.setOutput(ios);
    imageWriter.write(bi);
  }
```

(edited as corrected by @haraldK ).

Answer (score 2):

I printed the list of ImageIO informal formats, using the getReaderFormatNames method, on my Windows XP, Java 6 computer.

```
BMP, bmp, jpg, JPG, wbmp, jpeg, png, PNG, JPEG, WBMP, GIF, gif
```

Here are the equivalent MIME types

```
image/bmp
image/jpeg
image/png
image/gif
```

I couldn't find a MIME for the WBMP format.

Seems like you could just strip off the **"image/"** from the MIME to pass the informal format to the ImageIO read or write methods.

Comment: Thanks. I had already adopted your solution but it seems fragile (might have problems with case-sensitivity for example). I thought there must be a better way.

Comment: @peter murray rust: MIME descriptions are supposed to be lower case.  As you can see in my answer, the informal formats are both upper and lower case.  You can use the toLowerCase method when you're stripping the "image/".

Comment: Understood. But we may have a problem with types such as JPEG and JPG. Is the mime type format always supported as an informal?

Comment: @peter murray rust: I'm not sure I understand your question.  The MIME is image/jpeg.  jpeg is one of the ImageIO informal formats.  image/jpg is not in the MIME list, although it might be used.  jpg is one of the ImageIO informal formats.

Comment: @peter murray rust: Here's the MIME list I used - http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

Comment: +1 for the answer. But I will wait to see if there are other javax solutions.